# how to set mask to GrabCut method in emgu-cv c#?

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

i am trying to use GrabCut method in emgu cv

this is my code

```
 Matrix<double> bg = new Matrix<double>(1, 65);

        bg.SetZero();



        Matrix<double> fg = new Matrix<double>(1, 65);
        fg.SetZero();


        Image<Gray, byte> mask =  new Image<Gray, byte>(img.Size);


        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(img.Cols / 4, 0, (int)((double)img.Width / (0.75)), img.Height );


        CvInvoke.GrabCut(img, mask, rect,
           bg, fg, 5, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.GrabcutInitType.InitWithRect);


        for (int x = 0; x < mask.Cols; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mask.Rows; y++)
            {
                if (mask[y, x].Intensity == new Gray(1).Intensity || mask[y, x].Intensity == new Gray(3).Intensity)
                {
                    mask[y, x] = new Gray(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    mask[y, x] = new Gray(0);
                }
            }

        }

        img = img.Mul(mask.Convert<Bgr,byte>());




        imageBox3.Image = img;
```

my img :

[image]

result :

[image]

but i want the t-shirt so i tried to use this mask ( i made it in photoshop)

mask :

[image]

and i changed the mask so my code became like that :

```
 Matrix<double> bg = new Matrix<double>(1, 65);

        bg.SetZero();



        Matrix<double> fg = new Matrix<double>(1, 65);
        fg.SetZero();


        Image<Gray, byte> mask =  new Image<Gray, byte>(@"C:\Users\iP\Desktop\exaples\mas.jpg");

        //here i set the only white pixels (foreground object ) to 1 and 0 for else
        for (int x = 0; x < mask.Cols; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mask.Rows; y++)
            {
                if (mask[y, x].Intensity > new Gray(200).Intensity)
                {
                    mask[y, x] = new Gray(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    mask[y, x] = new Gray(0);
                }
            }
        }


        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(img.Cols / 4, 0, (int)((double)img.Width / (0.75)), img.Height );


        CvInvoke.GrabCut(img, mask, rect,
           bg, fg, 5, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.GrabcutInitType.InitWithRect);


        for (int x = 0; x < mask.Cols; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mask.Rows; y++)
            {
                if (mask[y, x].Intensity == new Gray(1).Intensity || mask[y, x].Intensity == new Gray(3).Intensity)
                {
                    mask[y, x] = new Gray(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    mask[y, x] = new Gray(0);
                }
            }

        }

        img = img.Mul(mask.Convert<Bgr,byte>());




        CvInvoke.Imshow("result", img);
```

but i get the same result with the first mask (without the t-shirt)

where is the mistake in my code ??

and i tried to change Emgu.CV.CvEnum.GrabcutInitType.InitWithRect   to
  Emgu.CV.CvEnum.GrabcutInitType.InitWithMask

and i get this

[image]

Comment: I think I see the t-shirt that matches your mask in that final image.  What do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: @jwdonahue check [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d83/tutorial_py_grabcut.html) please , i want to make something like that i want to put small touch in mask like this toturial in the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code is working now :)

```
Matrix<double> bg = new Matrix<double>(1, 65);

        bg.SetZero();



        Matrix<double> fg = new Matrix<double>(1, 65);
        fg.SetZero();


        Image<Gray, byte> mask = new Image<Gray, byte>(img.Size);


        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(img.Cols / 4, 0, (int)((double)img.Width / (0.75)), img.Height );


        CvInvoke.GrabCut(img, mask, rect,
           bg, fg, 5, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.GrabcutInitType.InitWithRect);


        Image<Gray, byte> mask2 = new Image<Gray, byte>(@"C:\Users\iP\Desktop\exaples\mas.jpg");

        ////here i set the only white pixels (foreground object ) to 1 and 0 for else
        for (int x = 0; x < mask.Cols; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mask.Rows; y++)
            {
                if (mask2[y, x].Intensity > new Gray(200).Intensity)
                {
                    mask[y, x] = new Gray(1);
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
        }

        CvInvoke.GrabCut(img, mask, rect,
             bg, fg, 5, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.GrabcutInitType.InitWithMask);


        for (int x = 0; x < mask.Cols; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mask.Rows; y++)
            {
                if (mask[y, x].Intensity == new Gray(1).Intensity || mask[y, x].Intensity == new Gray(3).Intensity)
                {
                    mask[y, x] = new Gray(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    mask[y, x] = new Gray(0);
                }
            }

        }

        img = img.Mul(mask.Convert<Bgr,byte>());




        CvInvoke.Imshow("result", img);
```

result :

[image]

video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=463TMas4vHU